# Generating HTML TestNG reports

Tags: testng

I want to generate HTML testNG reports. By default we have a report  file after running testNG called "emailable-reports". But now i want to create my own HTML report. I tried to use ITestListener and ITestReport.But even if i override those methods it is not doing any thing. I dono how and where to use those methods. I have two test cases. So now where i have to put the code to produce reports...

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html), implementations of the [ITestListener](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITestListener.html) interface are designed for real-time reporting, while implementations of the [IReporter](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IReporter.html) interface are intended to generate reports after the suite run is finished.

Implementing an instance of IReporter and the `generateReport(List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory)` method should allow you to look at the test results and create an HTML report.

Comment: Can you give me some example to generate reports. Because i tried to generate reports but Am getting error.

Comment: @Kalpana: Please add more detail about the error you're getting to your question above so we know how to help.

Answer (score 1):

@Feanor - As per your implementataion

```
################
  Implementing an instance of IReporter and the generateReport(List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory)
#################
```

We have a problem here. 
Assume we have implemented as instance of Ireporter say "CustomReporter" and override generateReport which gets called by adding listener in xml file

After this testng will ALSO call EmailableReport which also implements Ireporter which reverts back to default testNg report

Answer (score 0):

you can use [QAF](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf) with which you will be able to generate [json based reporting dashboard](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I have explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47309879/how-dataprovider-publish-the-test-data-into-html-report/47426325#47426325) how to customize `TestHTMLReporter` and here it is:

With your `customReport` You'd have to implement `IReporter` , extend `TestListenerAdapter` and override `generateReport` method if you want to implement a custom [`TestHTMLReporter`](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/TestHTMLReporter.java) . For other reporters you may have to do things a bit  differently but the concept will remain the same. You'd achieve custom 'TestHTMLReporter' like below .

Create a `CustomReport.java` file in your project and copy-paste the whole content of `TestHTMLReporter.java` , change the name of file in `getOutputFile` method  and it would look like below

```
public class CustomReport  extends TestListenerAdapter implements IReporter {

     @Override
        public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites,
                                   String outputDirectory) {

        }
   ...
   //paste the content of TestHTMLReporter.java here
   ...
   ...
```

Make sure all your imports are in place from `TestHTMLReporter.java`
Now, in this file  change as per your requirement . For ex: if you'd like to add the end time of each of the test then at the correct place in `generateTable` method  add the below snippet

```
// Test class
      String testClass = tr.getTestClass().getName();
       long testMillis = tr.getEndMillis();
        String testMillisString = Long.toString(testMillis);
      if (testClass != null) {
        pw.append("<br>").append("Test class Name: ").append(testClass);

         // this line to add end time in ms
        pw.append("<br>").append("End Time(ms): ").append(testMillisString); 
        // Test name
        String testName = tr.getTestName();
        if (testName != null) {
          pw.append(" (").append(testName).append(")");

        }
```

Then you'll get like below

[image]

Now, You'll get two reports one with default and the other with your file name.
The only thing now remains is switching off the default reporting listeners, so you get only one report. For that you can follow [this](http://testng.1065351.n5.nabble.com/How-to-disable-a-specific-default-reporter-and-listener-td23194.html) or you may search for solutions. Hope this helps