# Generating HTML TestNG reports

Tags: testng

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating HTML TestNG reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433544/generating-html-testng-reports)

Hi,
  I have two methods: addUser() and deleteuser(). Now I have to generate a HTML report for that using TestNG. I am using Selenium to test our website. So while running it is generating it's own html file. I want to create my own. My class structure looks like this:

```
public class test{

setup method
testcase method
stop method
}
```

Now where I have to include code for generating reports. I didn't have any idea about this. Actually I tried to use ITestListener and IReporter but they ask me to override generateMethod. But I don't know how to use those methods. Can anyone guide me with sample code ?

Comment: Let your report on web: https://vigoreport.io

Answer (score 0):

The documentation explains how to do this, along with an example:

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging

Comment: The example there is unclear, incomplete, and contains at least one mistake (at `for (ISuiteResult sr : suiteResults.values())`). If the official documentation were clear to the OP, he wouldn't have asked the question.