# selenium functionality testing - how to generate reports and send mailing them

Tags: java, selenium

Actually I am not a tester but given a task on Selenium. I am already having some of selenium. This code actually does 'functionality testing of a website' in firefox browser.

Now my task is to send mail to receipients of selenium success/failure report. At first, I am not understanding how to generate reports of success/failure. While searching in google, I found 'TestNG', I think I can make use of TestNG to generate reports and then send mail?

Please tell me if there is an easy way to generate selenium functionality testing reports and then send email of those reports.

Answer (score 0):

Using `TestNg`is the easiest way. You can take help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433544/generating-html-testng-reports). It will automatically generate the reports for you and if you want more customise report you can use [ReportNg](http://reportng.uncommons.org/)