# Open source to generate TestNG reports

Tags: java, report, testng

in contrary to the question: [Generating HTML TestNG reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433544/generating-html-testng-reports)

we already have testNG for integration (java), and we generate HTML reports and logs in our code, 
I now seek for alternative option to generate nicer HTML logs & reports.
I found only allure and extent(which support HTML logs only on pro version), is there any recommended options?
positive point given for:

1. built it HTML logger
2. open-source Jenkins integration
3. nice UI
4. easy to implement on existing java code
5. standalone library (not require another server)

   **EDIT**
   In addition, at least for our CI , we consider using ELK for the reporting (maybe also for logging, but it more complicated..) 
   seems it should be easy, by just generate JSON output in the reporter/logger
   is anyone did it? is it reasonable design?

Comment: is JMeter relevant here? it has all you ask, but I don't know if that's what you need, can you give a use case of what you will do with this?

Comment: Extent had HTML report in community/free version also. The logs are console logs in pro version.

Comment: thanks. I don't think JMeter will fit. basically, we have 2 UIs: 1. reporter dashboard with summary and tailed status of the Test status. 2. Logger which enabled developer/platform logging on HTML, including screenshots for selenium and UI testing

Answer (score 4):

For Java you won't find anything better.

[Allure Framework](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/)

1. Will require some coding to make your log looks nice.
2. [Allure Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Allure+Plugin).
3. Default UI good enough, could be changed with plugins.
4. We implemented it in 5-years old project with 20000 tests, took several days.
5. Standalone report, but it's developers has server version with several cool features.

[Extent Reports](http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/)

1. As you said - it is has it in PRO feature. But I suppose, that attaching whole logs to you reports it is not what you are really want.
2. As usual html report, no pipeline support.
3. UI good enough. Supports customisation with both JavaScript and CSS.
4. I have chosen Allure 1,5 years ago after spending several days trying to use ExtentReports for our huge test suite.
5. Standalone report available, as I know.
6. Klov report server can be used if you need to track historical data, view dashboard and analyse runs over a period of time.

[Report Portal](http://reportportal.io)

1. Can convert your logs in pretty looking test steps, will require some coding and refactoring.
2. [ReportPortal Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ReportPortal+Plugin)
3. Their team has UI Designer. This is all what need to know about their UI.
4. Same as for Allure, as for me.
5. It is a Portal. You will need small cluster to use it, see [docker-sompose](https://github.com/reportportal/reportportal/blob/master/docker-compose.yml).

Comment: Extent, the server is available with community version also, it's free.  Link. http://klov.herokuapp.com.  all customizations can be done to the free version also, but you need css and JavaScript skills.  The dev of this library said klov is comparable to Allure.. as the standalone HTML report is one of a kind.

Comment: Thanks for note, a year ago there was no klov.

Comment: thanks for detailed answer, we also taking in consideration also ELK, at least for the reporting task (assuming we already have ELK for CI).

Comment: As for me ELK is not good choice for that kind of tasks, I mean test reporting. It will require logs manipulating and parsing in logstash, configuring elasitc and kibana. While dedicated reporting tools do it from the box and also helps to organize your code.